# Placing a List in the parameters of another List in java

Tags: java

Sorry if the title is unclear, but I wasn't exactly sure how to describe this in that little amount of words. Okay, so suppose we have this declaration:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
//add items to list
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>(list);
```

Now, from what I understand, `set` will receive the data from `list` and sort them because that's what TreeSets do. However, on the oracle website, I don't see any constructor in the HashSet class that takes a List as a parameter. So, I don't understand why this works if there is no defined constructor to accept a List as a parameter.

Comment: Your first line of code would be better written `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`, Using the interface to hold your parameter is preferred unless there is some reason you want to explicitly know it is an `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TreeSet` has a constructor that takes a `Collection`, and `List` *is* a `Collection` (`List`  extends `Collection`).

Many classes in the Java collections framework follow the same concept. `ArrayList`, for instance, also has a constructor that takes a `Collection`. This makes it easy to copy data between collections.

Comment: Implements, not inherits from.

Comment: @davin I'm talking about the `List` interface, not the `ArrayList` class. `List` is an interface, and it inherits from (or _extends_) the `Collection` interface. `ArrayList` implements `Collection`.

Comment: Agreed, "implements" isn't the right term either, I still feel funny with "inherits from" though. Extends seems better.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TreeSet(Collection c)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Collection%29). This accepts a `Collection` and `ArrayList` implements `Collection`.